# Word order in product name

Tags: word-order, names

I am confused about word order when using the name of the product and its colour. For example: the product’s name is “Barrel Bag”. It comes in black colour. So what is correct here:
Buy our Black Barrel Bag
or
Buy our Barrel Black Bag
Should I use name of the product then colour and then type of the product? Or is it colour-name-type?

Comment: Keep the name together; and if "black" is a description and not part of the name, it should not take a capital 'B'.

Comment: Black could be part of the product name. Colours can be part of a name. Eg  "Red Label Tea"

Answer (score 1):

The words "Barrel" and "Bag" are both nouns. "Barrel" tells you what kind of "Bag" you are buying. The rule to follow here is: adjective - descriptive noun - head noun.

As mentioned in the comment, if "black" is part of the name it should be in capital letters.  Hence "Black Barrel Bag"

The other possibility you describe would work like this:

- **Barrel-Black Bag** This means that the bag is black and Barrel is the kind of "black" color that is used. In this case, you could also describe another product as Chestnut-Black Bag. Yes, the hyphen would be necessary (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Compound-Adjectives.htm).

Comment: Compare "Cadbury white chocolate". Here "white chocolate" is a type of chocolate, and the expression "white chocolate" is well known to have that particular meaning. This is not the case with "black bag", where 'black" normally refers only to the colour a bag happens to have.